# Oracle works better with Windows or Linux? give your answer based on your experience

Tags: database, oracle

In most cases I am used to work with Windows, some weeks ago I started to work with Oracle, I have experience with other DBMS like SQL and MySql and I have worked with them in Windows.

Now I am learning Oracle and I don't know **in which OS oracle works better**. I have installed it in windows but not in Linux. I also downloaded the Oracle Enterprise Linux which is an Linux OS for Oracle (similar with RedHat).

I want to know **if Oracle Enterprise Linux is the only one Linux OS where Oracle can be installed** or we can install Oracle even in RedHat, Ubuntu etc.

Also if someone has experience with this issue please let us know in which OS Oracle works better. I am confused with this problem and an answer from a profesional DBA will be very helpful for me.

---

So who can tell us which version of Oracle 11 is for linux, since i want to install Oracle on RedHat it will be good if some one let me know what is the Oracle version for Linux (redhat). Also it will be good if i have some link where it shows step by step Oracle installation on redhat. 
Thanks for your answer. You helped me to make the decision in which os to run Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can download the Oracle 11 instalation files for linux. 32 and  bits are available. RedHat is one of the easiest distros for installing oracle, but there are some differences between the different versions of RedHat (and the different versions of Fedora core too) so search for the right "step by step" document of you don't have any experience in the setup process.

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/index.html

Good Luck ;)

Answer (score 7):

At our company, we administer dozens of databases. They are split pretty much 50/50 between Windows servers and *nix (UNIX or Linux). Both of which are running significant applications (health and financial sectors). I suppose it's a matter of personal preference (and licensing fees!). You should be safe going with either. Note that Oracle Enterprise Linux is pretty much a re-packaged version of Red Hat. If you want to try a Red Hat derivative out for <s>cheap</s> free, try CentOS. However, CentOS is not officially supported by Oracle.

Comment: CentOS is an free OS, i am hearing for first time this os

Comment: @AXheladini: This is true. Thanks for clarifying. My brain and my hands were thinking two different words.

Comment: Tried Oracle 10g on CentOS and it works.

Comment: It should work.  However, neither Oracle nor Red Hat will have any obligation to help you if it doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, the main issues with Oracle on Windows are a result of Windows file locking.  For example, if the database was running and the data files for Oracle were locked by another process (i.e. a file system backup agent), we've had occurrences where the file has become corrupt.

Unix/Linux on the other hand doesn't seem to have those issues (according to our DBA).

In general, I've had no major issues with Oracle on a Windows Platform if steps are taken to ensure files are not locked by other processes.  We now use RMAN to perform online backups and exclude all Oracle data files from the file system backup.  It has been very stable for over 2 years now.

Answer (score 6):

I've used Oracle on both for several years.  I prefer Linux because:

1. Oracle releases patches, new versions, and sometimes security updates for Linux significantly before they are available for Windows - there's usually about a two month lag for Windows.
2. Our Windows servers have crashed or locked up occasionally, and very frequently require reboots for patch installation.  Oracle itself stays up very nicely, but Oracle can't keep running on a machine that is down.  This hasn't been a problem for me on Linux.
3. Oracle's interaction with Vista's User Access Control is a nightmare.  I'm constantly finding that the dedicated Oracle user account, which was used to install Oracle, nonetheless lacks permission to edit or even see Oracle-generated files - like newly generated logfiles.  It could be that I'm making some mistake, but permissions shouldn't be confusing; and on Linux, they aren't.  (Most servers don't run Vista, but I'm afraid of what this forebodes for future versions of Windows Server.)
4. Thanks to the Windows Registry, cleanly removing an installation of Oracle from Windows is tricky and tedious.  The Oracle Installer has gotten better at this since version 10g, though.
5. Better tools.  Linux *find* is infinitely better than any native Windows search tool.  Also, Oracle uses and generates plenty of plain-text files, and Linux comes with better tools for handling text files - good text editors (unlike Notepad), shell commands like grep.  You can try to catch Windows up by installing Geanie, Cygwin, Google Desktop, etc. on a Windows machine, but it's better not to have to (especially since Cygwin installation is not completely newbie-friendly).

I can only think of one Windows advantage over Linux:

1. In Oracle's command-line tools like sqlplus, rman, etc., you can scroll through and re-run past commands using the up- and down- arrow keys - but only on Windows.  You can fix this on Linux by installing *rlwrap* and always invoking the Oracle tools under rlwrap: "rlwrap sqlplus me/mypassword@myinstance".

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced Oracle installations on both Windows and Linux, all of them work as expected. Technically, you can install Oracle on almost every version of Linux, but if you want official support, you have to stick to Oracle's list of supported distros.

Answer (score 3):

CSC researcher Steve Ries wrote a paper on this subject "Head To Head: A Comparison Between Windows and Linux as an Oracle Database Platform" back in 2008.

Essentially, he built two servers on identical hardware (Dell 6800's, 16 GB of RAM, four 3166 MHz processors with hyper threading), installed Windows Server 2003 and RHEL 3 (update 4).  After installing Oracle 10g and importing identical data sets, he ran a series of experiments designed to test throughput and resource utilization.

His findings indicated that Oracle on Linux experienced:

> - SQL transformation statements that ran 30% faster with 6% less CPU
> - High I/O insert/selects that ran 160% faster
> - Statements that utilize parallelism with almost linear scalability resulting in twice  the performance
> - Exports that ran 300% faster

Of course, that experiment was run 5 years ago with software that was already (at the time) 4 or 5 years old.  So take that for what it's worth, but it at least gives you some indicators to watch for to ascertain how well 11g would perform on more-recent versions of each OS today.

Answer (score 2):

When I was working in Development + Support for Oracle (albeit over 7 years ago now), everything I was aware of ran on Solaris.  I understand that they now run a Solaris/Linux mix.

I would expect that Oracle would chose the most suitable O/S to run their own systems to run on....

Answer (score 2):

will you also be the DBA?  Or is it a case of developing an app that will hit Oracle and somebody else has to worry of administration duties?

If it is the former, then you'd get up and running faster with Oracle on windows.

If the latter, then go with Oracle on linux.  You'll have to get used to the command line but once you do it will be much easier and more powerful to administer your db on linux.  The day to day tasks in keeping it running smoothly, archiving data, importing data - all of it is made easier through the command line.

We have over 100 servers to administer on my team, a mix of SQL, Sybase and Oracle on windows and unix variants.  Oracle on linux gives us the least amount of problems by far.

Comment: So I am on my master studies on the field of Database Management and i hope i will be good DBA after i will finish my master studies. Also i told you that i dont have experience with Oracle i have only worked with sql an MySql. 
Based on that what you have written i wanted to asko one more question. In some cases you are writing that i will need to work on Command Line, Does this means that Oracle does not Have UI for LINUX os ?

Comment: oracle has many tools for the UI for all platforms. It is just that the command line affords you so much power to fit your specific needs, rather than a UI that is confined.  If you learn shell scripting or Perl, you will find many administration things can easily be done.  good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Oracle on any flavour of Linux. There's just a version that comes in RPM (RedHat Package Manager) for easy installation. For other variants, the installation is slightly more manual.

The other thing I'll mention is that unless you need the full-blown Oracle, just stick with Oracle XE (Express Edition). You can actually use that one commercially within the limitations (eg I think it only uses one core and up to 4GB of data). But for Windows in particular it comes with an easy installation process and HTML based admin tools (somewhat similar to MySQLAdmin).

For high end platforms, Linux/Unix tends to be preferred over Windows but that's probably not an issue for you. If you're just developing and aren't yet comfortable with Oracle, make it as easy on yourself as possible and stick with Windows and Oracle XE.

My experience has been that we've only ever used Windows as a server platform because we've had to (eg to run SQL Server, Exchange or whatever), not because we've wanted to. This applies equally well to Oracle where every Oracle installation I've ever used has been on Solaris or a Linux variant (primarily Red Hat but also Ubuntu).

The cost of the operating system is only reason to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I my last work, we migrate from windows to OpenSuse 11.

I spend a day in the instalation process (4 hours only to make appear the first screen of the oracle setup)  but now the users confirm me that the time of all the querys are now better, so I recomend it.

Answer (score 1):

We run Oracle instance on both Windows and Linux in our shop, and Oracle is definitely more responsive on Linux than Windows.  I run Oracle XE locally and I had to move over to Linux because on Windows Oracle crippled my machine.

We've also run into issues with SSL connections with Oracle running on Windows.  The network traffic is at least 20x slower with SSL on Windows (frequently resulting in application hangs) than on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I think as long as the platform is supported by Oracle, there probably won't be much of a difference.  However, if you need to scale - like really, really big - nothing is going to compare to Solaris.  Not too many companies need that, though.

Answer (score -1):

here are some good reference on installing oracle on linux.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/Articles10g.php#DB10gInstallations

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/Articles11g.php#db11g_release_1_installations

Answer (score -3):

ORACLE can be installed on linux ....but it does not support rhel 4.....it should be rhel 5

Comment: -1 It can definitely be run on RHEL 4... we're running 10g on it now.  I think we ran 9i on RHEL 2